# Wordpress - Gantry Framework

Tags: php, wordpress

I have  installed.

I installed the plugin Gantry framework and everything worked well. 
When I edit wp-config.php then it appeared error .. 
first i return the original wp-config.php but its same again.

The site address is http://www.balkanlife.net and the following is the issue:

```
Warning: session_start(): open(/tmp/sess_c8f005a6152407d7c72930471b314416, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13) in /home/balkanli/public_html/wp-content/plugins/gantry/functions.php on line 182

Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/balkanli/public_html/wp-config.php:1) in /home/balkanli/public_html/wp-content/plugins/gantry/functions.php on line 182

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/balkanli/public_html/wp-config.php:1) in /home/balkanli/public_html/wp-content/plugins/gantry/gizmos/iphonegradients.php on line 32

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/balkanli/public_html/wp-config.php:1) in /home/balkanli/public_html/wp-content/plugins/gantry/gizmos/iphoneimages.php on line 33

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/balkanli/public_html/wp-config.php:1) in /home/balkanli/public_html/wp-content/plugins/gantry/gizmos/iphonegradients.php on line 32

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/balkanli/public_html/wp-config.php:1) in /home/balkanli/public_html/wp-content/plugins/gantry/gizmos/iphoneimages.php on line 33

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/balkanli/public_html/wp-config.php:1) in /home/balkanli/public_html/wp-content/themes/paula/widgets/viewswitcher.php on line 50

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/balkanli/public_html/wp-config.php:1) in /home/balkanli/public_html/wp-content/plugins/gantry/gizmos/iphonegradients.php on line 32

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/balkanli/public_html/wp-config.php:1) in /home/balkanli/public_html/wp-content/plugins/gantry/gizmos/iphoneimages.php on line 33
```

Any ideas would be most appreciated.
Tnx